# Trigger Slack Bot by Direct Message

Tags: php, bots, slack-api

I'm realy new to this Bot stuff. 
I want to create a simple PHP-Skript that is sending an answere every time the Bot is contacted by a user via Direct Message.
I read the Api-Docs but the only thing I found was the /-Command.

Currently I have a Cronjob thats checking the RTM-Api for new messages.

I think there must be a better way then running a Cron-Job every few seconds to check if there is a new message for the Bot.

I found the "EmojiBot" that is exactly responding in the way I want.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the RTM API to build a bot will work, but there is indeed an easier way: Use the new Event API from Slack.

The Event API allows you to subscribe to range of events. When the event happens, Slack will automatically call your php script. So you don't need to run a CRON loop. This also works with bot users and direct messages to bot users.

Check out the [Event API documentation](https://api.slack.com/events-api) for details.

Comment: Works great for me. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. Please check this answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Botonomous Framework](https://botonomous.io/) which supports Events API. You should subscribe to the events, then update the framework configurations which is explained [here](https://github.com/iranianpep/botonomous/wiki/Listener-Types). Finally you have got a nice event object and based on certain criteria you can send a message back to a Slack channel.